# Nuclear rockets and EMPs

Tags: science-based, hard-science, spaceships, nuclear

Nuclear rockets, or as I like to think of them, "half way between a continuous small atomic explosion and reactor whose front fell off". There are many variants, and my aliens are using relative simple [nuclear salt water rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_salt-water_rocket).

The [Wikipedia page on EMPs shows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_electromagnetic_pulse) that the strength of the EMP from a nuclear bomb is significantly affected by the environment, so a detonation in near-Earth space (400km) creates a much more powerful EMP than the same size detonation within the atmosphere.

How would the exhaust plume of a nuclear rocket interact with Earth's atmosphere, magnetosphere, and ionosphere? Is there any risk of inducing significant currents on or near the surface (effectively, if not literally, an EMP) when the engine is switched on?

On the assumption that engine size has some effect on the answer:

- **Scout:** About the same size as a space shuttle, give or take, but with a max delta-V of ~400 km per second. Can sustain 55.88 m/s² for ~30 minutes. This one goes into Earth orbit at $some_altitude. How far away does the ship have to be to not cause problems?
- **Colony ship:** I'm not sure exactly how large, and I suspect I will be vague when describing it, but *large*. 130,000 colonists (each about half the weight as a human, and crammed in like… perhaps not literally sardines, but they're not having much fun). Max delta-V 40 km per second. This vessel lands on Earth (well, on water). This ship is designed to land directly without waiting in orbit. How will the engines affect electronics in the surrounding continent, if at all? Assuming the engines *must* be turned off at some altitude (and they switch to chemical rockets for the remainder of the descent), what altitude would that be?

**Edit:**

On the recommendation of comments, I'll accept [science-based] answers as well as [hard-science] answers. [hard-science] still preferable, if it's possible.

Comment: A shuttle sized spaceship, I'd imagine, would use some pretty teensy volumes on fuel and might not actually be a serious issue, but the colony ship is *definitely* going to wind up spraying everything in nuclear waste as nuclear reactors generate radioactive by-products and the local inhabitants might not appreciate being dowsed in unstable actinides.

Comment: They absolutely don't appreciate it, but they don't get any say in the matter either. :)

Comment: I doubt the question can get good hard-science answer in the way as it is described in [its about section](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tags/hard-science/info). It seems more appropriate would be science-based tag for the case. The problem is in first place - which type of nuclear engine do they use.

Comment: I would recommend Winchell Chung's Atomic Rockets website:
http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#id--Nuclear_Thermal--Gas_Core--Open_Cycle--Nuclear_Salt_Water. There's a lot more info there than on Wikipedia.

Comment: @MolbOrg I wasn't sure either, I was vacillating between hard-science and science-based when tagging it. But hard-science is preferable, if it exists.

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce Aye, I saw that when making notes on engine performance (because it's important how long it takes them to get from $plot_device to Earth) — But I see no sign of "does this induce significant electrical fields on a nearby planet?" unless I replace NSWR with Orion?

Comment: @MolbOrg extra question, as it's too late for me to edit previous comment: Is it allowed to tag as both hard-science and science-based?

Comment: just mention as a comment that you prefer the answer to be hard as possible. No, hard-science is superior to science-based - so science-based tag should be removed if there is a hard-science tag. If you will edit that, do not forget to flag it for mods to remove the warning plate. If you will be dissatisfied with results you might try to post the question in hard-science version later, try to appeal to the [metapost](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4407/20315). But first try to get the answer will it be an EMP for the situation and pick a particular type of engine(main problem).

Comment: A suggestion: drop the hard-science tag as it requires equations, research citations, and detailed answers. As it stands no-one can answer your question. However, a nuclear rocket isn't the same thing as a nuclear explosion, continuous or otherwise, and there won't be any EMP. Nuclear pulse propulsion vehicles might generate EMP, but nuclear salt water rockets. Landing your Colony Ship would be a nightmare. Too impracticable to be possible for reasons I can't answer because of your hard-science tag.

Comment: @a4android and BenRW, you don't have to drop the hard-science tag if you don't want. The things you ask for are possible to calculate. Just as a warning though, there is pretty much no good reason to use a nuclear-salt rocket in the atmosphere of a planet that other people want to live on, as the highly radioactive fission products are just sprayed out into the atmosphere. So while it is answerable, the question isn't very valid in its current form, as using a nuclear salt rocket on Earth is more or less an attempt at genocide.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the problems area of the page for [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)#Potential_problems) at wikipedia indicates that one of the most serious problems would be the flooding of the [Van Allen belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Allen_radiation_belt) (wiki too) with ionising radiation! Most of the data in the problems section for Orion do not apply to your issue directly but that one definitely does - the citations contain more information that you might be able to use too. No safety or environmental impact study has been done for that type of propulsion as of yet but it is a cool idea.

In order to address the more direct question of how far you'd have to go to be safe, realistically, we could deduce from the numbers pulled before the CTBT if you supplied a number in petajoules p/s of energy output for your rocket, I think.

Comment: An excellent point, I wish I'd seen it earlier in the day so I could comment properly and not sleepily. Back-of-the-envelope calculations look like the scout's engines are ~10TW (assuming similar mass to space shuttle and scaling from the projectrho.com link in the comments above), so 18 petajoules total for arrival and departure. That exhaust is going to be moving against the solar wind at between 1/3rd and 1/6th the speed of the solar wind as the ship slows down… my gut feeling says that means the exhaust will be trapped in the Van Allen belts, not escape to the wider system.